# Tomcat7 : Error on rendering js file with Invalid XML

Tags: javascript, json, tomcat

The js file(jquery.js) while rendering on Tomcat 7 thorws Error : Invalid XML in Firebug Errors Console.
Error: Invalid XML:

```
"<Data><code>ABC</code><codeName>Name</codeName><num>12345</num><dis>100</dis><area>123</area><sortBy></sortBy><model></model></Data>"
```

Works fine on Weblogic. Anything specific with Tomcat like strict validation against XSD? Just wondering.

Comment: What is the exact XML error you are seeing?

Comment: Did you deliberately used double quotes around the xml or it is coming  as a response from server. If it's coming as a response from server, compare this in both the server results.

Comment: not deliberate. thats how the error message is displayed in firebug.

Comment: the xml is not enclosed in <xml> tag?